# Ligatures not exporting to PDF after migrating to Windows Server 2012

Tags: pdf, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm-2011, reportbuilder3.0, windows-server-2012-r2

Since migrating from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2012, ligatures (eg. "fi") are getting replaced with X's when a report is exported to PDF. This occurs when exporting directly from Report Builder 3.0 on the server, and also from any Dynamics CRM 2011 client. The version of SQLServer/SRSS is 2012.

These same reports and same font (Calluna Regular) have always worked fine for us on Windows 2008/SQL 2008. I have observed that on 2012 the ligatures are visible in the text from Report Builder before exporting whereas on 2008 you do not see them at all.

So what can I fix to be able to continue exporting all text successfully?  I should add we are viewing the PDFs with Adobe Reader 11.0.07.

Happy to provide screenshots to illustrate the problem, but not sure how to attach them here as this is my first post. Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I used FontForge to remove the ligature glyphs from the font in question.  So that one's solved but I'm sure it will come up again.  Interesting that a different TT font also containing ligatures renders to PDF just fine, although it does it using the individual letters not the ligature.  The problem must be in how the PDFs are created by SRSS; any further insights from anyone will be appreciated.